# How to show all users name in SQL

Tags: sql

How to show all user name even count is zero.

```
$users = DB::select('select count(c.status) as countEvent, sum(c.point) as totalPoint,u.name from users u left join campaign_users c on u.id=c.user_id where u.deleted_at IS NULL group by u.name order by countEvent desc');
```

I want to count every user attend how many events but some of them not attend at all which is zero. I want to display all but the result only displayed users who attend at least one.

```
users - id, name     

campaign_users - status (1 for pending, 2 for attend, 3 for absent), point
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are interested in countEvent and totalPoint values only for status = 2 (i.e. Attend)

```
SELECT      u.name 
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countEvent
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 2 THEN c.point ELSE 0 END ) AS totalPoint
FROM        users u 
LEFT JOIN   campaign_users c 
ON          u.id=c.user_id 
WHERE       u.deleted_at IS NULL 
GROUP BY    u.name
```

It will be great if you can provide the sample data and intended output to understand your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the right way to do it is to query first the names and then count the results of the query .

Comment: It will be better if you will provide the data tables and your desired output .